# Device not found [init]

Tags: python, usb

I tried to connect to a device called "Rigol DP832". In the past it worked, but now it doesn't even work with the old program.

I tried to connect with it via usbtmc:

```py
inst = usbtmc.Instrument("USB0::0x1AB1::0x0E11::DP8C224104355::INSTR")
```

It shows
`usbtmc.usbtmc.Intrument Device not found [init]`
and doesn't show when I use

```py
usbtmc.usbtmc.find_device()
```

but it shows up in the program from it and even in the device manager.

Why did it work in the past, but not anymore?